# Protein degeneration/excretion in cell

Tags: cell-biology, proteins

If I inject a dose of GFP or some other types of protein into a long-living human cell like brain neuron cell. Will these proteins being degenerated or excreted over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper](http://peds.oxfordjournals.org/content/12/12/1035.long) gives a half-life of 26 hours for wild-type GFP expressed in mouse cells.